# php Laravel cannot store input value to database

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently working on a laravel php project, the project previously connected with slack and send notifications to slack. Now I need to send notifications to Teams, so I need to follow the previous slack notifications. for the database, I have a user table contained slack_incoming_hook, and I added a column called 'teams_incoming_hook' just like "slack_incoming_hook". Next, I modified user.php file, it has a creation function and a store function to create and store the input value. I added teams_incoming_hook following slack_incoming_hook.
user.php:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $fillable = [
        
        'slack_incoming_hook',
        'teams_incoming_hook'
    ];
    static public function create(Request $request){
        $user = new User;
        $user->slack_incoming_hook = $request->slack_incoming_hook;
        $user->teams_incoming_hook = $request->teams_incoming_hook;
        $user->save();
    
 }
 
 static public function store(Request $request){
    DB::transaction(function () use ($request) {
        $user = User::find($request->id);
        if($user){
            if($request->slack_incoming_hook != ""){
                $user->slack_incoming_hook = $request->slack_incoming_hook;
            }
            if($request->teams_incoming_hook != ""){
                $user->teams_incoming_hook = $request->teams_incoming_hook;
            }
            $user->update();
        }
 }

 }
```

here is the edit-user.blade.php code:

```
<div class="col-span-3 sm:col-span-2">
    <label for="slack_incoming_hook" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
        Slack Webhook Url
    </label>
    <div class="mt-1 flex rounded-md shadow-sm">
        <input type="text" name="slack_incoming_hook" id="slack_incoming_hook" class="focus:ring-green-200 focus:border-green-200 flex-1 block w-full rounded-none rounded-l-md rounded-r-md sm:text-sm border-gray-300" value="{{ $user['slack_incoming_hook']}}">
    </div>
    <x-small-text.danger class="slack_incoming_hook_error"></x-small-text.danger>

</div>
<div class="col-span-3 sm:col-span-2">
    <label for="teams_incoming_hook" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
        Teams Webhook Url
    </label>
    <div class="mt-1 flex rounded-md shadow-sm">
        <input type="text" name="teams_incoming_hook" id="teams_incoming_hook" class="focus:ring-green-200 focus:border-green-200 flex-1 block w-full rounded-none rounded-l-md rounded-r-md sm:text-sm border-gray-300" value="{{ $user['teams_incoming_hook']}}">
    </div>
    <x-small-text.danger class="teams_incoming_hook_error"></x-small-text.danger>
</div>
```

and I tried to modify the User table directly and the value can show on the UI page.
Please help me to figure it out. Many THX!

Comment: You have two `static public function create(Request $request)`??

Comment: emm actually one is named "create", the other one is named "store"

Comment: Not in the code you posted, no. Two `function create`, one `function store`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reminding, I just updated my code.

Comment: So you're probably trying to use the static function store() in your model, correct? Then try to debug what's in your request. If the user isn't found then nothing happens at this point. Try to check what's coming in your controller after you have posted the form. `dd();` is your friend

Comment: On a sidenote, since you are not using the fillable way of updating the user record, it's not really adding anything to have a $fillable for the User model. I'd even argue to not add anything to $fillable that is not used in that manner.